# For Scala 2.13, what is the fastest method for updating a LongMap, HashMap, or TrieMap with millions of updates?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, scala-2.13

**Goal**

I have a mutable Map[Long, Long] with millions of entries. I need to make many iterations of updates with millions of updates. I would like to do this as fast as possible.

**Background**

Currently, the fastest method is to use a single threaded mutable.LongMap[Long]. This type is optimized for Long types as the key.

Other map types appear to be slower -- but I may have implemented them incorrectly as I was trying to do the updates concurrently and/or in parallel without success. It is possible that updating a map in parallel is not actually occurring or is not possible in Scala.

In order of fastest to slowest:

1. LongMap[Long] (from above)
2. TrieMap[Long, Long]
3. ParTrieMap[Long, Long]
4. HashMap[Long, Long]
5. ParHashMap[Long, Long]
6. ParMap[Long, Long]

It is OK if a faster method is not mutable, but I do not think this will be the case. A mutable map is probably best for this use case.

**Code to generate test data and time the test**

```
import java.util.Calendar
import scala.collection.mutable

object DictSpeedTest2 {

  //helper constants
  val million: Long = 1000000
  val billion: Long = million * 1000

  //config
  val garbageCollectionWait = 3
  val numEntries: Long = million * 10 //may need to increase JVM memory with something like: -Xmx32g
  val maxValue: Long = billion * million // max Long = 9223372036854775807L
                                         // this is       1000000000000000L

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    //generate random data; initial entries in a; updates in b
    val a = genData(numEntries, maxValue, seed = 1000)
    val b = genData(numEntries, maxValue, seed = 9999)

    //initialization
    val dict = new mutable.LongMap[Long]()
    a.foreach(x => dict += (x._1 -> x._2))

    //run and time test
    println("start test: " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime)
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis
    b.foreach(x => dict += (x._1 -> x._2)) //updates
    val end = System.currentTimeMillis

    //print runtime
    val durationInSeconds = (end - start).toFloat / 1000 + "s"
    println("end test:  " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime + " -- " + durationInSeconds)
  }

  def genData(n: Long, max: Long, seed: Long): Array[(Long, Long)] = {
    val r = scala.util.Random
    r.setSeed(seed) //deterministic generation of arrays
    val a = new Array[(Long, Long)](n.toInt)
    a.map(_ => (r.nextInt(), r.nextInt()) )
  }
}
```

**Current timings**

LongMap[Long] with the above code completes in the following times on my 2018 MacBook Pro:

- ~3.5 seconds with numEntries = 10 million
- ~100 seconds with numEntries = 100 million

Comment: First this is far for being an appropriate way to test the performance of two implementations. Take a look to proper benchmark tools like **ScalaMeter**. Second, mutability + concurrency / parallelism will lead to many headaches. It may help describing what are you trying to model here and why performance is too important for you in this use case.

Comment: I understand that it is a rough approach -- I just made it simple for this post. I identified the dictionary updates as the bottleneck in my larger workflow with the Profiler in IntelliJ. I will take a look at ScalaMeter as I have seen it mentioned a few times now.

I am hoping for a solution that is an order of magnitude better, which would be obvious with this simple time tracking.

Comment: Still you haven't answered what is the purpose of this mutable map and why performance is too important.

Comment: Sorry. I missed that question. I am tracking updates to a large dictionary that holds labels for ~250 million dictionary entries. In spurts, I get ~100k to ~200k updates from some streaming graph analysis that I wrote. I would like this portion to speed up because there is additional analysis that I could perform and report on in-between the batches of updates. This dictionary is the center-point for my state.

Comment: Have you considered moving that state outside your app. For example to a database, for example **Mongo**? Or even better to a distributed cache like **Redis**? Or maybe using other technologies to process that amount of data, like **Spark** or **Scio**?

Comment: I don’t see how adding a database would add speed. Even and in-memory database would slow down my process because I still need access to the statement after the updates.

Comment: Regarding Spark, I use Spark daily and have for years. The entire analysis could be migrated to Spark. It Might actually be slower. I need to consider that as a solution. Currently, our shop does not have a Spark cluster that stays up 24/7. I spin up an AWS EMR cluster as needed. I’ll take a look at Scio. That is new to me.

Comment: Thanks for the effort and comments. Upvoted all above.

Comment: Yeah, I was referring more to the ability of keeping all that mutations outside your code, sometimes you can optimize the algorithm in different ways. **Scio** would not work for you if you use **AWS** as it integrates well with **Dataflow** service in **GCP**. PS: You may also see if `streaming` would help, take a look to **fs2**, **Monix** or **Akka Streams**.

Comment: I am very familiar with Akka Actors and have dabbled with the streams library. I really want to keep the state in this module. Going outside of the app would slow things down and require pulling some state back in. Latency matters here. I imported FastUtil and received an almost instantaneous 8x speed increase. That will be good enough for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not limited to use only Scala/Java maps than for exceptional performance you can peek 3rd party libraries that have maps specialized for Long/Long key/value pairs.

[Here](http://java-performance.info/hashmap-overview-jdk-fastutil-goldman-sachs-hppc-koloboke-trove-january-2015/) is not so outdated overview of such kind of libraries with benchmark results for Int/Int pairs.

Comment: I found that exact article the other day. FastUtil might be exactly what I want. I intend to test it later today.

Comment: FastUtil is really fast. No false advertising here. Thanks.